# Plotting resampled time-series area chart with one line of code?

Tags: python, plot, time-series, timeserieschart

I'm trying to find a way to efficiently/quickly plot a resampled time series area plot in one line of code.

Let's say I have a simple time series; I know I can use the following method

```
    SERIES.resample('M').mean()
```

to create a new time series (resampled to the Month via mean).
I know I could just do

```
    df=SERIES.resample('M').mean()
    df.plot(kind='area')
```

And be done--but is there another way to do it via one line of code? I looked at

```
    plt.fill()
```

and

```
    plt.stackedplot()
```

But those require x,y arguments

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
SERIES.resample('M').mean().plot(kind='area')
```